# Get specific string in a column and then change it Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have dataset with a column that contains negativ numbers (-14, -16,...) but sometimes the datasets only contain "-" without a number. If that happens i won't to change it into 0 and then afterwards change the dtype to int64.

i tried it with df['Level'].str.contains('-') but this is true for all cells.

Comment: what's the question? convert it to integer column?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) and then [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype)

Ex.:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Level':[1,-2,'-',2]})
>>> df
    a
0   1
1  -2
2   -
3   2
```

```
>>> df['Level'] = df.Level.replace('-',0).astype('int64')
>>> df
   Level
0      1
1     -2
2      0
3      2
>>> df['Level'].dtypes
dtype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
df['Level'] = np.where(df['Level']=='-', 0, df['Level'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and `fillna` is your safest bet, plus your columns will also be converted to numeric:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Level':['-16', '-14', '-']})
>>> df
  Level
0   -16
1   -14
2     -
>>> df['Level'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Level'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
>>> df
   Level
0  -16.0
1  -14.0
2    0.0
```